# how can my ms access cancel-button call the same event/code as the X in the corner?

Tags: ms-access

I have an MS Access database/application.

I have a form on which I create a new record.

When the user chooses the X in the corner of the window, then this message is shown:

> You can't save this record at this time.

> [form-title] may have encountered an error while trying to save a record.

> If you close this object now, the data changes you made will be lost.

> Do you want to close the database object anyway?"

On that form, I also have a cancel button with the VBA code `DoCmd.Close`

When the user chooses the cancel button, then the above message is **not** shown...

What can I do, so that the above message is shown, when the user chooses the cancel button?

In other words: I want the cancel-button to call the same event/code as the X.

thanks

Comment: You may be benifited from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63922918/access-vba-preventing-form-record-entry-on-close/63930745#63930745)

Comment: thanks, Harun, for your reference to custom-made code. I prefer using the code that ms access already has for the X.

Comment: try: `DoCmd.Close , , acSavePrompt`

Comment: thanks, jbud, no effect

Comment: I don't think you can access that native code, you'll have to write your own. For consistency, it's often best to hide X button and write your own save and cancel buttons. It's been a while since I worked with this, maybe you can `DoCmd.Close` *without* saving and it will bring up the prompt?